# How can I draw an ellipse in benzene molecule?

Tags: chemfig

Can you help me to draw an dash ellipse in benzene molecule and adsorption bond from the molecule center to the metal?

[image][image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\begin{center}
\setcrambond{2pt}{}{}
\chemfig{H-[8,0.5]?<[7,0.7](-[5,0.5]H)-[8,,,,line width=2pt](-[7,0.5]H)>[1,0.7](-[8,0.5]H)-[3,0.7](-[1,0.5]H)-[4]?(-[3,0.5]H)}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your example code produces errors. Please fix it.

Comment: The error is corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can draw an invisible bond to the center of the ring, name that position with `chemfig`'s `@{name}` syntax and draw a slightly longer bond from there to Me.

With the `\chemmove` macro and a little bit of TikZ you can draw the ellipse around the marked center:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\setcrambond{2pt}{}{}
\chemfig{
  H-[0,0.5]?(-[,.9949,,,draw=none]@{center}-[6,1.5]Me)
   <[7,0.7](-[5,0.5]H)
   -[0,,,,line width=2pt](-[7,0.5]H)
   >[1,0.7]@{C4}(-[0,0.5]H)
   -[3,0.7](-[1,0.5]H)
   -[4]?(-[3,0.5]H)
}
\chemmove{
  \draw[dashed]
    (center) + (.8,0)
    arc [x radius=.8, y radius=.4,start angle=0,end angle=360];
}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, it is very good. I intended to use the @ {}, but did not know how to draw an ellipse and position it in the center. Thank you.

Comment: The only inaccuracy in your code: there is necessary (center) + (-2.494,0) instead of (center) + (.8,0) in chemmove. Thanks again.

Comment: @Evgeni actually no: the image I attached was produced with the code I posted so it's correct. But you can still adapt the code as you like it

Comment: You are right. Probably it is the problem of my TexPad application (ellipse was shifted). When I run the code in TexStudio on PC image was right.

Answer (score 1):

With a lot of stacking, and a little `tikz`.

EDITED to provide thinner ring, and ability to break ring.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chemfig,stackengine,graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor,tikz}
\newcommand\dottedcirc[2]{\tikz{\draw[dashed] (0,0) arc [x radius=.8,%
 y radius=.4,start angle=#1,end angle=#2];}}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\begin{center}
\stackunder[-6.6ex]{
\stackinset{c}{0pt}{c}{}{\dottedcirc{0}{360}}{%
\setcrambond{2pt}{}{}
\chemfig{H-[8,0.5]?<[7,0.7](-[5,0.5]H)-[8,,,,line width=2pt](-[7,0.5]H)>[1,0.7](-[8,0.5]H)-[3,0.7](-[1,0.5]H)-[4]?(-[3,0.5]H)}
}
}{\stackon{Me}{\rule{1pt}{9ex}}}
%
\stackunder[-6.6ex]{
\stackinset{c}{-6pt}{c}{}{\dottedcirc{55}{305}}{%
\setcrambond{2pt}{}{}
\chemfig{H-[8,0.5]?<[7,0.7](-[5,0.5]H)-[8,,,,line width=2pt](-[7,0.5]H)>[1,0.7](-[8,0.5]H)-[3,0.7](-[1,0.5]H)-[4]?(-[3,0.5]H)}
}
}{\stackon{Me}{\rule{1pt}{9ex}}}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. However, the ring got too thick. Besides, I have not written immediately, I need the opportunity to break this ring while sequential hydrogenation (new image added at the top).

Comment: @EvgenyChem I have managed to make the ring thinner (see edit).  Still thinking on a partial (broken) ring.

Comment: @EvgenyChem Please see my revision.

Comment: Oh! Thank you very mutch. This is what I wanted.

Comment: I saw the the stackengine package firstly. I think this problem can be solved by chemfig or tikz.