# How can I create the following reactions with help of chem figure package?

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

I am trying to draw the following reactions with help of chem figure package in latex.
[image]
i am not able to figure out how to draw the molecules under which π is written (last five molecules in which Pt is attached with some kind of bond). So, please help me with following tasks:

1. write a proper latex code to correctly draw the reactions in the above picture.
2. how to include 'Gas' and 'Ads.' on the left side of reactions in the way similar in above picture.

I am a beginner in `chemfig` and I have been able to create something like this
[image]
with

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{chemfig,mlmodern}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{[:30]*6(------)}
    \arrow{<=>[*{0}--H][*{0}+H]}[-90]
    \chemname{\chemfig{(-[::90,0.4])(-[::180,0.4])-(-[::-112.5,0.4])(-[::67.5,0.4])-[::-45](-[::-112.5,0.4])(-[::67.5,0.4])-[::-45](-[::0,0.4]Pt)(-[::90,0.4])-[::-90](-[::-112.5,0.4])(-[::67.5,0.4])-[::-45](-[::-112.5,0.4])(-[::67.5,0.4])-[::-45]}}{$\alpha$}
    \arrow(.0 --.base west){<=>[--H][+H]}   
    \chemname[-5ex]{\chemfig{[:45](-[::90,0.4])(-[::180,0.4])-(-[::-112.5,0.4])(-[::67.5,0.4])-[::-45](-[::-112.5,0.4])(-[::67.5,0.4])-[::-45](-[::0,0.4])(-[::90,0.4])-[::-90](-[::-112.5,0.4])(-[::67.5,0.4]Pt)-[::-45](-[::-112.5,0.4])(-[::67.5,0.4]Pt)-[::-45]}}{$\beta \alpha$}
    \arrow(.base east--.base west){<=>[--H][+H]}
    \chemname[-5ex]{\chemfig{[:45](-[::90,0.4])(-[::180,0.4])-(-[::-112.5,0.4])(-[::67.5,0.4])-[::-45](-[::-112.5,0.4])(-[::67.5,0.4])-[::-45](-[::0,0.4])(-[::90,0.4])-[::-90]-[::-45]-[::-45]}}{$\pi$}
    \schemestop
\end{document}
```

but the way i have created it feels like kind of a hack and not the proper solution.

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230352/how-can-i-draw-an-ellipse-in-benzene-molecule might give you a start.

Answer (score 1):

I created a "standalone" document, this will generate a PDF figure that can be inserted into another document.
I didn't use \chemname because using this command the name of the molecule becomes part of the molecule, which makes it difficult to position the molecule. To place the names, I placed markers on the molecules (@{}) and created invisible arrows with boxes \parbox
The design of the molecule is a little different, but I think it turned out good.

to know which molecule is C4, enable \setchemfig{scheme debug=true}

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig,mlmodern}

%to make double-pointed bonds
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{ddbond}{initial}
{
    \state{initial}[width=4pt]
    {
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{4pt}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{2pt}{2pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{4pt}{2pt}}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{4pt}{0pt}}
    }
    \state{final}
    {
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
    }
}
\tikzset{lddbond/.style={decorate,decoration=ddbond}}
\tikzset{rddbond/.style={decorate,decoration={ddbond,mirror}}}

\begin{document}
%   \setchemfig{scheme debug=true}
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{[:30]*6(------)}
    %
    \arrow(--){<=>[*{0}--H][*{0}+H]}[-90]
    %
    \chemfig[cram width=2pt]{?(-[3,0.4])(-[5,0.4])<[7,0.7](-[2,0.4])(-[6,0.4])-[@{a}0,,,,line width=2pt](-[2,0.4])(-[6,0.4])>[1,0.7](-[1,0.4])(-[7,0.4])-[3,0.7](-[2,0.4])(-[6,0.4])-[4]?(-[2,0.4])(-[6,0.4])}
    %
    \arrow( --.mid west){<=>[$-$H][+H]}  
    % 
    \chemfig[cram width=2pt]{?(-[3,0.4])(-[5,0.4])<[7,0.7](-[2,0.4])(-[6,0.4]Pt)-[@{b}0,,,,line width=2pt](-[2,0.4])(-[6,0.4]Pt)>[1,0.7](-[1,0.4])(-[7,0.4])-[3,0.7](-[2,0.4])(-[6,0.4])-[4]?(-[2,0.4])(-[6,0.4])}
    %
    \arrow(.base east--.base west){<=>[--H][+H]}
    %
    \chemfig[cram width=2pt]{?(-[3,0.4])(-[5,0.4])<[7,0.7]-[0,.5,,,line width=1pt,lddbond](-[2,.4])(-[6,.4]@{c}Pt)-[0,.5,,,line width=1pt,lddbond]>[1,0.7]@{x}(-[1,0.4])(-[7,0.4])-[3,0.7](-[2,0.4])(-[6,0.4])-[4]?(-[2,0.4])(-[6,0.4])}
    %
    \arrow(c4 --){<=>}[90] 
    %
    \chemfig{[:30]*6(=-----)}
    %
    \arrow(@{x}--){<=>[$-$H][+H]}[0]
%----------------------------------------------------
\arrow(@{a}--){0}[290,.6]\parbox{1cm}{$\alpha$}
\arrow(@{b}--){0}[290,.5]\parbox{1cm}{$\beta\alpha$}
\arrow(@{c}--){0}[300,.2]\parbox{1cm}{$pi$}
    \schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]